# laravel 4 simple route not working

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

I have a working laravel installation to which I wanted to add a route but it wouldn't work.

```
Route::get('asdf', function() {return "asdf";});
```

All the other routes work but new ones don't, not even controller ones. I have just tried to simplify an example above to post here.

1. I created a github project with the full project
   [laravella\laravella](https://github.com/laravella/laravella/tree/develop-vg)
2. Cloned the project
3. Deleted compiled.php
4. Ran `composer install`
5. Ran `php artisan dump-autoload`
6. Ran `php artisan serve --port 80`

The server console reports this error :

```
[Fri Jul 12 10:11:11 2013] 127.0.0.1:51042 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Fri Jul 12 10:11:11 2013] 127.0.0.1:51043 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Fri Jul 12 10:11:11 2013] 127.0.0.1:51044 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
```

Below is the log.

Thanks.

```
[2013-07-12 08:29:44] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php:290
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->missingMethod(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php(138): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller.php(115): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->callMethod('missingMethod', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(4741): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->callAction(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), 'missingMethod', Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(7810): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(7797): Illuminate\Routing\Route->callCallable()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(4752): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(480): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\bootstrap\compiled.php(469): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\lv\laravella\server.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#12 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Do you run PHP 5.4? Try to use other, non PHP server. Run ***curl http://localhost:8888/laravel-clean/public/asdf*** What is the output?

Comment: curl works if I remove the other routes in the routes.php

Comment: I have moved the '/' route to the bottom of the routes.php file and everything seems to work now.

Comment: Just something to add... Take a look at [this post](http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out) on [laravel.io](http://laravel.io) which sums up the importance of route order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `Route::get('asdf', function() {return "asdf";});` is above controller routes if you have any because controller routes are greedy they won't let `Route::get()` handle their routes as it should have.

**Edit** Looking at your github clone `routes.php` its like

```
Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
Route::get('asdf', function() {return "asdf";});
```

so in order to make your `Route::get('asdf','...');` to work just add it above controller routes ex-

```
Route::get('asdf', function() {return "asdf";});
Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

And it will work